# Cannot process new line '\n' delimiter in a string

Tags: c++, string, algorithm

I am trying to reverse a string with the following code:

```
string reverseStringHelper(const char* s, bool flag) {
        if(*s == '#') {
            return "";
        }
        if(flag) {
            return reverseStringHelper(s+1, 0) + *s + "\0";
        } else {
            return reverseStringHelper(s+1, 0) + *s;
        }
    }
    string reverseString(string s) {
        s = s+'#';
        return reverseStringHelper(s.c_str(), 1);

    }
```

I works perfect for test cases like:
`"Hello"`, `"Hello World"`

But fails for cases like:

```
"Hello World
New World!"
```

Why is that can anyone explain?

Comment: Try with a shorter string (so there's not so many recursive calls) and then step though the code in a debugger, stepping into the recursive calls. Check the values of `s` and `*s` and what the previous recursive call returned (might want to use temporary variables to store the result just to be able to debug easier).

Comment: Can you explain how it fails?

Comment: I don't know the C++ standard library but does `str + "\0"` produce a different value than `str` (given `string str;`)?

Comment: @axiac: Yes. `std::string` is binary-safe and can store `'\0'` like any other character. I don't really understand the use of `'\0'` here, though. The OP seems to be getting confused, mixing C and C++ idioms.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure why you're adding the `#` character as `c_str` will give you a pointer to a null terminated string, but if you want a more C++ friendly way to reverse a string just use `rbegin` and `rend`:

```
std::string text = "Hello, world";
std::string reversed(text.rbegin(), text.rend());
```